# t-sql get record where date is exact match or within specified minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select

I'm looking to get a record where the date is either an exact match or within 5 minutes.

```
SELECT @TripId = t.Id
        FROM Obd.TodaysTrip t WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE (t.DeviceId = @Id)
          AND (t.LastAccOnTime = @LastAccOnTime)
```

When I pass `@LastAccOnTime` I would like to also match on one single record that is at the most 5 minutes prior to the current greatest `t.LastAccOnTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) in this manner, to get the time 5 minutes ago:

```
AND (t.LastAccOnTime = @LastAccOnTime 
     OR t.LastAccOnTime BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -5, @LastAccOnTime) AND @LastAccOnTime)
```

Comment: This is better than the answer by @murienic because it can use an index.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`datediff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) function to check the difference between `t.LastAccOnTime` and `@LastAccOnTime`:

```
SELECT @TripId = t.Id
FROM   Obd.TodaysTrip t WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE  (t.DeviceId = @Id) AND 
       (ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.LastAccOnTime, @LastAccOnTime)) <= 5)
```